# Ionic React - set navigations based on a parameters

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react, ionic6

I need to handle the navigation based on a parameter with a button click event.
In **ionic angular** I can easily do it like

```
 setNavigation(param:string,url:string)
  {

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
          type: param
      }
    };
    
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward([url],navigationExtras);
  }



goNextPage()
  {
      this.setNavigation('param1','nexthome');
                        // parameter , url 
  }
```

How can i achieve same thing when I'm using **Ionic React** ?

Simply my need is to navigate from one page to another based on a parameter

Comment: can you be more specific? providing an angular example is a good start... are you asking how to pass a parameter when using react-router?

Comment: @AaronSaunders yes I learned lot of things from your tutorials as well.But in this case i really need to do same thing as above.     Pass a parameter with react router and get that parameter in next page.Then navigate based on that parameter

Answer (score 0):

Ionic React doesn't provide any tools for this out of the box, but you can easily use one of the many React query string libraries.

For example, I wanted to parse URLs like this:

`myapp.com/edit/123?&dest=review`

For example, in my router, I added a route like this:

```
<Route exact path={`edit/:articleId`}>
  <ArticleEdit />
</Route>
```

And then in the `ArticleEdit` component, I parse the query string:

```
  import { useParams } from 'react-router';
  import queryString from 'query-string';

  const { articleId } = useParams<{ articleId: string }>();

  const parsedQueryString = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
  const { dest } = parsedQueryString;
```

Hopefully this gives you some idea of how you can accomplish what you want.